# Execute SSIS Package using Execution account credentials

Tags: ssis

I am troubleshooting an SSIS package, permission issues around external files.

It only fails when running via the SQLAgent obviously using the SQL Agent unattended account.

This is fixed now however in order to test I needed to create a SQLAgent job and then a step within that job to test.

Obviously when a package is run locally via Visual studio it uses your own credentials. When you log into SSIS server via Management studio and use the Execute package utility does this use your own credentials or the SQL Agent credentials?

Is there any quick way of executing a package with the Agent without going through the fuss of creating an Agent job?